# How to replace a shared file when deploying code with Capistrano?

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

*Update: TL;DR there seems to be no built-in way to achieve this, so a custom task is an easy solution.*

Capistrano provides facilities to share files and directories over all releases. This is convenient and provides even some safety on files that should not be easily changed (or must remain the same across releases), e.g. a database configuration file.

But when it comes to *replace* or just update one of these shared files, I end up doing it manually, directly on the target machine. I would like to improve on that, for instance by asking Capistrano to overwrite some or all shared files when deploying. A kind of `--force` flag with some granularity.

I am not aware of any such kind of facility, and failing so far in my search. Any pointer?

---

#### Thinking about it

One of the reason why this facility does not exist (except that I did not find it!) is that it may be harder than it looks. For example, let's assume we have a shared database configuration file, and we exclude it from version control for security reason (common practice). Current release relies on version 1 of the DB configuration. The next release requires version 2 of the DB configuration. If the deployment goes well, everything's good. It gets harder when *rolling back* after some error with the new release (e.g. a regression), as version 1 *must* then be available.

---

Such automation would be cool and convenient, but dangerous as well. Yet I have practical use cases at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a `template` method to do this. For example, I could have a task like this:

```
task :create_database_yml do
  on roles(:app, :db) do
    within(shared_path) do
      template "local/path/to/database.yml.erb",
               "config/database.yml",
               :mode => "600"
    end
  end
end
```

And then I have a `database.yml.erb` template that uses things like `fetch(:database_password)` to fill in appropriate values. You can use the `ask` method in Capistrano to prompt for these values so they are never committed.

The implementation of `template` can be very simple: you just need to read the file, pass it through `ERB`, and then use Capistrano's `upload!` to place the results on the server.

My version is a little more complicated than yours probably needs to be, but in case you are curious:

https://github.com/mattbrictson/capistrano-mb/blob/7600440ecd3331945d03e059368b75849857f1fb/lib/capistrano/mb/dsl.rb#L104

Comment: Thank you for the detail. I should have said that I'm already doing a similar approach. "Manual" meant "not already in there"... That answers the question, though, so marked as the one.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use a system configuration tool like Chef or Puppet to deploy the configuration files distinctly from Capistrano.

Another approach is to create a custom task to do this: https://coderwall.com/p/wgs6gw/copy-local-files-to-remote-server-using-capistrano-3

I personally don't change on-server configs often enough or on enough servers yet to have tried to automate it. Crafting an scp command which copies the desired config file to all of the required servers has sufficed in the past.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I'd say using an external tool just to do that is overkill.